# Using Three JS and img to create a 3d cookie cutter?

Tags: javascript, php, three.js

So what I am trying to do is grab the edges of a black and white image.
Then create a 3D model that will show the edges of the black shape then extrude the edges for depth and extrude the walls for thickness and finally extrude the edges again to create a handle. For an example see: https://cookiecad.com/ Use the ice cream shape to see what I am looking for. I don't expect to be handed the code just some guidance on what parts of Three JS and PHP I need to use. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Finding the edges of a black and white image you have to walk all the pixels and find the outline. In the worst case you'd just make edges for every pixel that has no neighbor on that edge and you'd get a pixelated outline. Making it less pixelated would require curve fitting or some other algorithm.

But, assuming you have that shape you can extrude a cross section of the cutter down the path using the [ExtrudeBufferGeometry](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-primitives.html#Diagram-ExtrudeBufferGeometry)

If the cross section looks like this

```
     +--+
     |  |
  +--+  |
  |     |
  |  +--+
  |  |
  |  |
  |  |
  |  |
  |  |
  |  |
  |  |
  |  |
  |  |
  |  |
  +--+
```

you'll get your cookie cutter

Comment: Perhaps I'm an idiot how would I walk the pixels? I am new to Three.js and haven't worked with SVG very often

Comment: You can load an image then draw it into a 2D canvas and use [getImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) to read the pixels. Covnerting them into lines as I said at the top of the question you can walk the pixels and make an edge for every pixel's edge that has no neighbor. If you want smoother curves though [I don't see any simple solutions](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+image+to+vectors+algorithms). If you have SVGs then dig through [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_svg.html)